# x axis at our desired number of points

Tags: plotting, spacing

I have:

```
tmax = 1.2*0.1*10^11;
Plot[t^5, {t, 0, tmax}]
```

[image: dd]
Then I get a picture as above. This is pretty easy data and the width of two points in x axis won't affect the clarity of the figure. I used this example to let you know my requirement.
In MATLAB, we have an option to set the width of the x axis. Look at the second line of the below code in MATLAB.

```
tmax=1.2*0.1*10^11;
tt=0:0.1/100*10^11:1.2*0.1*10^11;
```

How to select the plot width as 0.1/100*10^11 in mathematica as easy as in MATLAB. I have asked a similar question earlier and the suggestion I got is really difficult and I didn't really understand. Is there any easy way? I have searched the documentations and can't come up with any!

Comment: Could  you clarify what you mean by "select the plot width as 0.1/100*10^11"? Do  you mean the x-axis range (can be set with the `PlotRange` option to `Plot`) or the actual width of the graph (look up `ImageSize` and `AspectRatio`)?

Comment: I meant 'dx' that is difference b/w two points in the x axis

Comment: Try `Plot[t^5, {t, 0, tmax}, Ticks -> {Range[0, tmax, .01*10^11], Automatic}]` where the third argument to `Range` is the step size.

Comment: Jasmine, can you, please, help to clarify what you mean by “difference b/w two points in the x axis”? By points, do you mean the tick-marks, as MelaGo shows how to control in their comment? Or do you mean points as in the actual points used to plot the equation?

Comment: What I meant is to draw a plot by taking t values in such a way that the first point is 0 , second point is 0.1/100*10^11, third point is 2*.1/100*10^11 and so on until 1.2*.1*10^11. This improves plots accuracy as we are using more data points.

Comment: @MelaGo Does this help to improve the accuracy of the plot? In some cases when I use this code, nothing is quoted in x axis!

Comment: Please do not keep posting new questions on the same topic. Instead, clarify your previous question, and address the comments there. If I understand your question, you want to use the `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` option of `Plot`. Note that Mathematica does not sample at regular intervals when plotting. It uses adaptive sampling. Look up `MaxRecursion` on the `Plot` documentation page to learn more.

Answer (score 2):

In Mathematica `Plot` will automatically choose where to evaluate the target function for you, so you cannot specify which points to use. You can control some aspects of this using various options, *e.g.* `PlotPoints`:

```
tmax = 1.2*0.1*10^11;
dt = 0.1/100*10^11;
Plot[t^5, {t, 0, tmax}, PlotPoints -> Round[tmax/dt], Mesh -> Full]
```

produces:
[image: Plot]

However, if you want full control over the actual points used for plotting, you should instead use `ListPlot`, *i.e.*

```
ListPlot[Table[t^5, {t, 0, tmax, dt}], Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

produces
[image: ListPlot]
which uses exactly the points you would get in MATLAB.

In either case, you should use the help function in Mathematica to investigate other relevant options for these functions.